# How Android ensures security?

Tags: android, security

I am just starting on Android development. To my nascent knowledge, it seems that anybody can grab any personal info and modify it or phone it home. Like with ContactContentProvider. I know these(permissions) have to be specifically declared in application manifest and the user would be presented with this info during installation. But still how would you you know the application handling your private data is not going to go rouge on it?

Example:

> Suppose I create an app with internet
>   and contact-reading permissions. It
>   claims that it will backup contacts on
>   a server specified by user. While
>   secretly it also copies them to your
>   own server.

Comment: Also, I think my question boils down to an open app store(Android) versus a closed one with a defined approval process(Apple).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no different than you developing an app that does it that runs on a PC, or something that uses your gmail login to see if there's others you know on the same site.

It's all about trust. Also the Apple approval process doesn't safeguard against any of this if you hide it and when found out malicious apps can be killed & uninstalled instantly.

Comment: I think what makes the case of Android different from Desktop is that, in former case, there is a well establish ecosystem for distribution and that too with very low entry threshold. So, anyone with $25(or so) can upload a app and reach millions of users. For a desktop developer to reach such mass it will take a lot more time and/or money.


Also, I think with a phone there is more damage a malicious code can do, knowing your location. Intercepting your calls may be. Camera is sure to be there. Such things are not sure to be there on a Desktop PC.

Comment: True, but on the android you still have to give the app these permissions. So it all comes down to if you trust the developer or not.

Comment: There are plenty of low-barrier ways to distribute desktop apps too, like download.com.